# Auto-LogOut if token is expired in next-auth v4

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth, next.js14

I am implementing credentials login using `Node.js` as the backend. The login process works smoothly, but let's say the token expiry is 15 seconds. I want the system to automatically log out after expiration, even if the page doesn't have any API calls.

I don't want to check if an API is returning `Token expired` and then log out. Suppose I have a dashboard page rendered after authentication, and the page doesn't have any API calls, then the sign-out won't be triggered.

I want to auto log-out as soon as the token expires, including on page refresh.

```js
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import CredentialProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        console.log("credentials", credentials);

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
        }).then((res) => res.json());

        // const user = { id: "1", name: "John", email: credentials?.email };
        console.log("user", response);

        if (response?.status === 200) {
          return { ...response.data };
        } else if (response?.status === 422 || response?.status === 401 || response?.status === 500) {
          throw new Error(response.message);
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any, user: any }) {
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },
    async session({ session, token }: { session: any, token: any }) {
      session.user = token;
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/", //sigIn page,
  },
};
```

```js
"use client";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";
import { Input } from "../ui/input";
import { Checkbox } from "../ui/checkbox";
// import GoogleSignInButton from "../github-auth-button";

const formSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().email({ message: "Enter a valid email address" }),
  password: z.string().min(6, { message: "Password must be at least 6 characters" }),
});

type UserFormValue = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

export default function UserAuthForm() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const callbackUrl = searchParams.get("callbackUrl");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const defaultValues = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
  };

  const form = useForm<UserFormValue>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues,
  });

  const router = useRouter();

  const onSubmit = async (data: UserFormValue) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await signIn("credentials", {
        redirect: false,
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        // callbackUrl: callbackUrl ?? "/dashboard",
      });
      console.log("response", response);

      if (response?.ok) {
        router.push("/dashboard");
      } else if (!response?.ok && response?.error === "fetch failed") {
        // set the error message to the form for something like network error
        form.setError("email", { message: "Network error" });
        form.setError("password", { message: "Network error" });
      } else {
        form.setError("email", { message: response?.error ?? "Invalid credentials" });
      }

      // form.setError("email", { message: response?.error ?? "Invalid credentials" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error", error);
      // check if error is of type InvalidCredentialsError or something else
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Form {...form}>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className="space-y-2 w-full"
        >
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="email"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter your email..."
                    disabled={loading}
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />

          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="password"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Enter your password..."
                    disabled={loading}
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />

          {/* <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
            <Checkbox
              disabled={loading}
              name="remember"
              control={form.control}
            />

            <label className="text-muted-foreground">Remember me</label>
          </div> */}
          <Button disabled={loading} className="ml-auto w-full" type="submit">
            Sign In {loading && "..."}
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Form>
      <div className="relative">
        <div className="absolute inset-0 flex items-center">
          <span className="w-full border-t" />
        </div>
        <div className="relative flex justify-center text-xs uppercase">
          <span className="bg-background px-2 text-muted-foreground">
            Already have an account
          </span>
          <span onClick={() => router.push("/register")}
            className="bg-background px-2 text-primary cursor-pointer">Sign Up</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* <GoogleSignInButton /> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried setting statically `maxAge:` which didn't work for me:

```js
  session: {
    // maxAge: 15 seconds
    maxAge: 15,
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when we work with jwt tokens, we get 3 types of tokens:

- Access Token
- Refresh Token
- Id Token

We use the `Access Token` to be able to make API calls. They have an expiration time and that's why we also have the Refresh Token to get a new Access Token once it's expired. Id Token generally includes some useful information about the authenticated user.

In your login endpoint which is `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/login`, I think you should return those 3 different type of tokens. **Assuming you do return them, I can go further in details.**

*(THIS MEANS: you should also return `accessToken`, `refreshToken` and `idToken` in your login endpoint response body along with `id`, `name` and `email`)*

Main idea is to check the session on each page without waiting for an API call and forward the users to the log in page once the access token is expired. I guess this is what you want.

Lets' begin.

1. Add `next-auth.d.ts` file under the types folder which is at the root level of your project. Without this file, you may get type errors.

```js
import { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface User {
        id: string
        name: string
        email: string
        accessToken: string
        refreshToken: string
        idToken: string
    }

    interface Session {
        user: User & DefaultSession["user"]
        expires: string
        error: string
    }
}
```

2. Change your jwt and session callbacks like this:

```js
async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
    if (account && user) {
        token.id = user.id
        token.name = user.name
        token.email = user.email
        token.accessToken = user.accessToken
        token.refreshToken = user.refreshToken

        // we'll get the expiration time of the access token
        const decodedAccessToken = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(user.accessToken.split(".")[1], "base64").toString())

        if (decodedAccessToken) {
            token.accessTokenExpires = decodedAccessToken["exp"] * 1000
        }
    }

    if (token.accessTokenExpires && (Date.now() < Number(token.accessTokenExpires))) {
       // the access token is still valid
       return token
    }

    // the access token is expired (please note that we can implement a "refresh the access token" mechanism here but we don't because you just want the user to be logged out once the access token is expired)
    return {
        ...token,
        error: "AccessTokenError"
    }
},
async session({ session, token }) {
    return {
        ...session,
        user: {
            ...session.user,
            id: token.id as string,
            name: token.name as string,
            email: token.email as string,
            accessToken: token.accessToken as string,
            accessTokenExpires: token.accessTokenExpires as number,
        },
        error: token.error,
    }
}
```

3. In this final part, we should check the session if it has "AccessTokenExpired" error. One way to do this is to put this logic inside a component which can be seen in every page in your application.

Let's say you have an Avatar component inside your Header component:

```js
import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Avatar() {
    const { data: session } = useSession()

    const logout = useCallback(() => {
        const accessToken = session?.user?.accessToken || undefined

        fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/auth/logout`, { // this comes from your .env file, e.x. http://localhost:3000 where your nextjs app runs
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({ accessToken })
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                /* send log to the Sentry if the endpoint fails
                if (!data.success)
                    notifySentry("Could not log out!")
                 */
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                /* send log to the Sentry if an error occurs
                notifySentry(error)
                 */
            })
            .finally(async () => {
                // after logout, we redirect user to the login page
                await signOut({ callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/login` })
            })
    }, [session])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('session: ', session)
        if (session?.error === "AccessTokenError") {
            // force the user to log out if the session has AccessTokenError
            logout()
        }
    }, [session, logout])

    return (
        <>
            <!-- code -->
        </>
    )
}
```

Of course, to be able to access the session, we should wrap it with `SessionProvider` in the header:

```js
"use client"

import React, { FC } from "react"
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

import Avatar from "./Avatar"

const Header: FC<HeaderProps> = () => {
    return (
        <SessionProvider>
            <!-- code -->
            <Avatar />
            <!-- code -->
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Finally our logout endpoint (path: `api/auth/logout/route.ts`):

```js
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json()

    // change the url with your logout endpoint
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/logout`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${body.accessToken}`,
        },
    })

    return Response.json({
        success: res.ok,
        status: res.status,
    })
}
```

4. Please be sure that you have the following variables in your `.env` file:

```
AUTH_SECRET=jk7uk0517804988p3f015a789ba997u6 // change with your own secret
AUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/auth
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Add this line in your `authOptions`:

```
secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
```

I guess this answer can give you an insight. Tell me if you need any changes.