NextJS save user information and token (from external API) for client and server components
I am working on a new web app in NextJS, it has client and server components. The user data is sent to an existing API (in .NET). I have to save the logged-in user's information e.g. name, id and token, so it can be used in the header for external API calls and to display in the site's header.
Could someone guide me on how to save this information so it could be used by both types of components?
Thanks

You can use Session from next-auth. For more insights and example, you may find some help from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78159089/auto-logout-if-token-is-expired-in-next-auth-v4/78212844#78212844

I recommend using NextAuth (https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example).
With this, you can manage the authentication state of your user completely. It sounds like you use email as your credentials' provider. In addition to the email, you can store any other user-related properties in your session token (e.g., the userId). This token can be accessed the following ways:
Server side:
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

Client side (make sure that you use the session provider):
const { data: session, status } = useSession()

